# Finding order of convergence using Taylor Series

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

The fixed point method $g(x)= x - \frac{f(x)}{2f ^\prime (x)}$ 
(can also be written as $x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{2f ^\prime (x_k)}$)
is similar to Newton's method except for the 1/2 coefficient. My question is how do I show the order of convergence for this method using Taylor series?

EDIT

I believe the goal is to get it into the form $|x_{k+1} - a| = C|x_{k} - a|^n$ and that $n$ is the order of convergence.

I tried getting it into the form $g(y) = g(x) + g^\prime(x)(y-x) + \frac{g ^{\prime\prime}(x)}{2!}(y-x)^2 + ...$

Since $g^\prime (x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 
\frac{f ^{\prime \prime} (x) f(x)}{[f^\prime (x)]^2}$

Substituting in I get $g(x_k) = g(a) + \frac{1}{2}(x_k -a) + \frac{g^{\prime \prime}(a)}{2}(x_k-a) $

But I'm not sure what to do from here

Answer (score 0):

Your last formula should be
$$
g(x_k) = g(a) + \frac{1}{2}(x_k -a) + \frac{g''(\tilde a)}{2}(x_k-a)^2
$$
Now $g(a)=a$ and thus
$$
|x_{k+1}-a|= \frac{1}{2}|x_k -a|+O(|x_k-a|^2)
$$
which is indicative of linear convergence.

---

Choosing a $C\in(\frac12,1)$ and $N$ large enough, the above equation can be weakened to 
$$
|x_{k+1}-a|\le C\,|x_k -a|
$$
for all $k\ge N$ resp. $x_k$ close enough to $a$.

Comment: Why are we able to write $\frac{g''(\tilde a)}{2}(x_k-a)^2$ as $O(|x_k-a|^2)$?

Comment: Because $g''$ is continuous (has as assumption that $f\in C^2$) it is locally bounded. Then apply the definition of the Landau notations.